# Excel vba - Split function gives 'Subscript out of range' error inside loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns with data.
Each cell is formatted: "***" or "XXX at mm.dd.yyyy", where XXX represent various numeric combinations, and I need to replace "XXX at mm.dd.yyyy" with "XXX", so I've done this:

```
For Each c In Range(.Cells(2, 9), .Cells(finalrow, 10))
        If c <> "***" Then
            c.Value = Split(c, " at")(0) * 1
        End If
Next c
```

but I get a 'Subscript out of range' error on the row 2345.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is row 2345?

Comment: Might be a blank cell, or value that doesn't fin into `"***"` format but doesn't have `at` delimitier. The problem is that that array you create doesn't have any items at all. Temporary fix is to add condition `If Ubound(Split(c, " at") >=0 Then`

Comment: Yes, that's it, there was a blank cell in the row 2330. It's my mistake.

Comment: @CreakushColiko so row 2345 actually meant your row in Excel? I am impressed.

Comment: Welcome!  Please check out the [tour] and also see [ask] as well as [mcve] prior to making an [edit] to your question or before your next post.  Thanks!

Comment: @AntiDrondert - you have missed a parenthesis before the `>=`. And it should be only `>`, not `>=`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it had to do something with the type of data (char, long, int, double, variant) and the bytes they use (so 2056 is 2^12), so I thought that's the reason behind the 'out of range error'

Comment: @Vityata Ops, my bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concerning that you probably get an error because of the empty 2345 row:

```
For Each c In Range(.Cells(2, 9), .Cells(finalrow, 10))
        If c <> "***" Then
            If InStr(1, c, " at ") Then
                c.Value = Split(c, " at")(0)
            End If
        End If
Next c
```

It checks whether there is " at " in `c`, thus the split will not result in an error.